# How can I hide a button after it was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a stop button,when it is clicked it gets hidden but when I fresh the page the button does appear again.Is it possible to hide the button forever even if there is a page refresh here is what I tried

```
   newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD('<input type="button" value="Stop" id="btnStopEvent">');

function GetEventId() { 
        $(document).on('click', '#btnStopEvent', function () {
            var EventId = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');   
            var Result = {
                EventId: EventId
            };                         
            $(this).hide();          
        });
 }
```

Comment: Use cookies for storing those details

Comment: If you are storing details in the database or any other place, then you can use the jquery's document ready event to hide the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to **persist the button's state** somewhere else. Every time you reload the page, your code is re-loaded and any **JavaScript variables that were set are initialized again.**

You could do something with [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage), there are many tools that make using Local Storage easy, here is a very simple example:

```
// set the value and save it in local storage
localStorage.setItem( "stop_button_state", "disabled" );
// after page re-load, fetch the saved value
var button_state = localStorage.getItem( "stop_button_state" )
```

You could also use some sort of server side persistance, it could be a session variable (PHP) or even stored in a database of some sorts. You would then retrieve the setting before serving the page to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies might be good for this case. You already use jQuery, so try this plugin

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

After that you need to write some simple logic to set cookie when button is clicked and check for cookie before clicking so that it wont show.

Localstorage is also good as someone already mentioned, if you aim only for moden browsers.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Please don't distribute links to w3schools - it really is not a good resource. Take a look at http://www.w3fools.com/ for more information.

Comment: I totally agree, however they are more stable (wont be removed) that the other sources.

Comment: Any and every link is subject to link-rot so I'm not too sure that argument is effective here... All I'm saying is that there are much much better (and more widely accepted) resources out there.

Comment: The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is one such example of a great alternative; and if we're still on your argument - I don't think firefox will be removed any time soon either ;)

Comment: I am not arguing with you, I agree 100%. However it is always a good idea to point to the official docs, no matter how bad are they ( just for referance).

Comment: And here is where the real problem lies... W3schools is by no means official! The **[W3C](http://www.w3.org/) is the actual official resource** - w3school's name is what created the confusion - they are in no way affiliated with the W3C.

Comment: Oh, good, didnt know that. I quess you learn something every day :)